# ios : UIScrollView scrolling reset controls position to initials

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am creating a Register screen where if user want to change PIN he should tap on change PIN label and it will add two UITextField Controls (New PIN and Confirm New PIN) after PIN UITextField and push the below fields 100 pixels below.

The problem is when I try to scroll the view to see the below controls it resets the controls (which I moved down) to the **initial positions**.

ViewDidLoad

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                     target:self selector:@selector(forScrollView)userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ShowChangePINFields:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    _lblChangePIN.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [_lblChangePIN addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

- (void) forScrollView {
    NSLog(@"setScrollEnabled");
    [self.scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 900)]; // must be greater then the size in Storyboard
}// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
BOOL isNewPINShow = NO;
    -(void)ShowChangePINFields:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
        NSLog(@"setScrollEnabled");
        isNewPINShow = NO;
        if(!isNewPINShow)
        {
           // [[self scrollview] setContentOffset:self.scrollview.contentOffset animated:NO];
            _tfNewPIN.hidden = NO;
            _tfConfirmNewPIN.hidden = NO;
            isNewPINShow = YES;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

            _tfConfirmNewPIN.frame = CGRectMake(306, 197, 292, 30);
            _tfNewPIN.frame = CGRectMake(306, 245, 292, 30);

            CGRect tempFrame = [_tfEmail frame];
            tempFrame.origin.y  = tempFrame.origin.y + 100;
            _tfEmail.frame = tempFrame;                

            tempFrame = [_tfLanguage frame];
            tempFrame.origin.y  = tempFrame.origin.y + 100;
            _tfLanguage.frame = tempFrame;

            tempFrame = [_tfSecretQuestion frame];
            tempFrame.origin.y  = tempFrame.origin.y + 100;
            _tfSecretQuestion.frame = tempFrame;

            tempFrame = [_tfSecretAnswer frame];
            tempFrame.origin.y  = tempFrame.origin.y + 100;
            _tfSecretAnswer.frame = tempFrame;               


        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it run the animation again? as isNewPINShow is always False

Comment: its working fine ... problem is that view resets controls positions to initial when I try to scroll the view

Comment: Have you tried to print the frame out to confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply disable "Use Autolayout" in the File Inspector in your storyboard.

[image]

Comment: its not storyboard, its .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to move from

> Scroll View > All Objects

to

> Scroll View > View > All Objects

Below is a sample image

[image]